# How to add functions to a MVC Joomla component to access data from a different table?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, crud, joomla3.2

I have a custom joomla MVC component created by http://component-creator.com with 4 tables:

```
#__mycomponent_items    27 Fields   
#__mycomponent_bids         12 Fields   
#__mycomponent_journeys     9 Fields    
#__mycomponent_users    8 Fields
```

I am trying to set the relationships between these tables, but in the absence of documentation and experience I am struggling.

The basic relationships between the tables need to allow USERS to make BIDS to deliver ITEMS.

So I have created fields for items like this:

```
#__mycomponent_items       
id
created
updated
ordering
state
checked_out
checked_out_time
created_by
deliverydestination
itemtitle
status
requiredby
listprice
deliveredprice
commission
points_reward
accepted_bid
accepted_bidder
accepted_journey
```

And for bid like this:

```
#__mycomponent_bids
id
state
created_by
item_id
buyer
bid
created
updated
bid_status
bid_expires
journey
arrival_date
```

I am working in templates/mytemplate/html/com_mycomponent/item/default.php and trying to add to that view a list of the current bids on that item. To do that I assume I need to add a custom function to /components/com_mycomponent/models/item.php and the function I have created is follows:

```
function itemBids() {
        // Get a db connection.
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select item record matching the $orderID
        $query
            //->select('*')
            ->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'created_by', 'created', 'bid', 'bid_status', 'arrival_date')))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__mycomponent_bids'))
            ->where('item_id = item.id');            
        // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.

        // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $itemBids = $db->loadObjectList();
        //print_r($itemBids);
}
```

How do I then access the data in the view /mytemplate/html/com_mycomponent/item/default.php?

I have tried this and it returns nothing:

```
<ul>
          <?php foreach ($itemBids as $itemBid) :?>
         <?php $arrivalDate = $itemBid->arrival_date; ?>
          <li><strong><?php echo $itemBid->created_by; ?></strong> <small>can deliver for</small> $<?php echo $itemBid->bid;?> <small>
          <?php /*?><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $itemBid->created; ?>"></abbr><?php */?>
          in <strong><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $arrivalDate; ?>"></abbr></strong></small><div class="uk-badge uk-float-right"><?php echo $itemBid->bid_status; ?></div></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be putting it in your template like that. the template just holds the layouts that generate the html.  Also you need to have a default layout in your views/myview/tmpl folder.

You don't seem to be returning anything from your `itemBids()` function.  You would want to add `return $itemBids;` or possibly `return $this->itemBids;` depending on what you are doing elsewhere.

YOu want to get $this->itemBids in your view.html.php class so that it is then available to your layout. THen instead of referring to `$itemBids` you can refer to `$this->itemBids` in your loop in the layout.

Have you been through the Creating an MVC Cmponent tutorial?  It would probably help you get a sense of how MVC works in Joomla.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really go into adding your own functions ok - so at the end of the function I now have this:     `$db->setQuery($query);
$this->itemBids = $db->loadObjectList();
return $this->itemBids;`

Comment: What format does the additional line in view.html.php take?

Comment: Adding your own functions is just that, add them, I'm not sure what the mystery is if you know how PHP works.  They are all added functions extending or adding to the functions in the base class.
Is all you want to render the current list of bids? OR do you want multiple complex lists.  Mainly I think you just need $items      = $this->get('bidItems');   but it's kind of hard to tell beause you are never showing the whole method even. It just seems like a standard getItems() to me though.

Answer (score 0):

OK , as far as I understand you have a method in yourmodel.php and you are trying to access it from the view I did notice that you are not returning any values in your method

```
    return $db->loadObjectList();
```

let me just make it simple by the below code

```
//com_component/models/yourmodel.php
class componentModelYourmodel extends JModelLegacy
{
function yourMethod()
{
//code
return $value;
}
}
```

And then in view file

```
//com_component/views/yourview/tmpl/default.php

//get the model first
$model=$this->getModel();
//call the method
$items=$model->yourMethod();
//print
print_r($items);
```